# Python (DICT) - Populated with JSON - Can't use variable in request

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I was wondering if you could help me with a piece of code i'm working on at the moment. I'm new to Python and this is one of the first major scripts i have tried to write.

```
import json, sys
from pprint import pprint
#Importing workbench json output into the python script.
with open('jsonoutput.json') as data_file:
    data = json.load(data_file)

#Sets the verible for the while loop.
x = int(0)

while x <= 1:
    y = x
    print type(data)
    jdata = data["result"]["items"][y]["tagValues"]["IdDevicesMap"]["value"]
    if setup_1(jdata) == True:
        Default_1 += 1
    else:
        print "exiting"
```

Error i get when it runs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 47, in <module>
    jdata = data["result"]["items"][y]["tagValues"]["IdDevicesMap"]["value"]
KeyError: 'tagValues'
```

Just on a side note as well, when i manually put in the list number [y] to 1 the code runs perfectly. So it's like its got an issue with the way I'm inputting the variable [y] into the request.

Comment: Seems like tagValues is not in some of the nested dictionaries you read from the file. Mind to provide the input ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure the json you read doesn't have tagValues in every one of them. You might wanna try `try`: and `except:`

```
import json, sys
from pprint import pprint
#Importing workbench json output into the python script.
with open('jsonoutput.json') as data_file:
    data = json.load(data_file)
x = 0
while True:
    try:
        jdata = data["result"]["items"][x]["tagValues"]["IdDevicesMap"]["value"]
        if setup_1(jdata) == True:
            Default_1 += 1
        else:
            print "exiting"
            break
    except KeyError:
        print data["result"]["items"][x]
        pass
    x+=1
```

To do it in a pythonic way :

```
import json, sys
from pprint import pprint
#Importing workbench json output into the python script.
with open('jsonoutput.json') as data_file:
    data = json.load(data_file)

for x, d in enumerate(data["result"]["items"]): #in case you need a counter
    try:
        jdata = d["tagValues"]["IdDevicesMap"]["value"]
        if setup_1(jdata) == True:
            Default_1 += 1
        else:
            print "exiting"
            break
    except KeyError:
        pass
```

Comment: Ahh awesome, that's exactly what was happening, for some reason i automatically assumed that there was a tagValue for each device, which was incorrect. Changed my code to handle that exception and it worked perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

This error simply means that you don't have a key called `"tagValues"`. This'll work if your `json` looks like this.

```
data = {"result":
         {"items":
           [ {"tagValues":
                 {"IdDevicesMap":
                   {"value":
                     {
                       #data
                     }
                   }
                 }
               }
           ]
         }
       }
```

So, either your data doesn't look like this, or if it does, then the key called `"tagValues"` is missing.

Another thing is tell if data["results"]["items"] a list or JSON?